# How to retrieve HttpResponseMessage FileName in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've this WebAPI method, that takes a custom object `MyType` as input and generate a PDF based on that. The PDF-file is returned as a `HttpResponseMessage`. Note that I specify the filename on `response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName`:

**ASP.NET WebAPI**

```
[Route("")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]MyType input)
{
    var pdfContent = PdfGenerator.Generate(input);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = pdfContent;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "MyCustomFileName.pdf"

    return response;
}
```

In AngularJS I fetch the file using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) like this:

```
$http.get("api/pdf/", {
    params: {
        "type": myObject
    },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).then(function (results) {
    var data = results.data;

    var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    saveAs(file, 'filename.pdf');
}, function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

It works as excepted, but I'm defining the filename both on WebAPI and in the JavaScript. Is there a way, that I can retrieve the FileName defined in WebAPI in the `results` variable in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The promise returned by methods of `$http` are passed as argument an object with the following properties ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)):

> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the  request.
> - statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

So `results.headers('Content-Disposition')` will gives you the value of the `Content-Disposition` header. You will have to do some trivial parsing to get to the actual filename.

Comment: This above solution is not working in Chrome as it just return the headers `Cache-Control` and `Content-Type`. Here is my post for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825590/web-api-is-not-returning-the-contentdisposition-filename

Comment: The previous comment is wrong because, as it is obvious from the answer of the linked question, the problem in the question is not Chrome, but the fact that the request is CORS and it needs explicit permission to access headers.