# Access HttpResponseMessage from Web API in AngularJs using $resource

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

I have a c# web api method that's returning integer value as `HttpResponseMessage`, would like to access the same from the response in AngularJs using $resource, How?

Web API:

```
[HttpPut]
        [Route("DeleteFile")]
        public HttpResponseMessage DeleteFile(int cabinetFileID)
        {
            var fileName = cabinetDataAccess.GetFilePath(cabinetFileID);                  
                var returnVal = cabinetDataAccess.DeleteCabinetFile(cabinetFileID, UserEmail);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnVal);                

        }
```

Service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('data')
        .factory('cabinetService', cabinetService);

    cabinetService.$inject = ['$resource', 'serviceBase'];

    function cabinetService($resource, serviceBase) {
            var deleteCabinetFileResource = $resource(serviceBase + '/api/Cabinet/DeleteFile?cabinetFileID=:cabinetFileID',null,{'update':{method:'PUT'}});

        return {                
            deleteCabinetFile: deleteCabinetFile
        };

        function deleteCabinetFile(cabinetFileID){
            return deleteCabinetFileResource
                .update({cabinetFileID:cabinetFileID},null)
                .$promise;
        }
    }
}());
```

controller:

```
function deleteThumbnail(cabinetFileID)
        {
           cabinetService
            .deleteCabinetFile(cabinetFileID)
            .then(function (data) {
                //How do i Access my return value here ???
                //Something like 
                if(data.returnVal === -1)
                //do something
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                growl.err('Unable to delete  file, Please try later !', {ttl: 20000});
            })
        }
```

This code is getting me the response, how do i need to access the return value from data ?

Comment: When you execute your code, what contains data exactly ?

Comment: No its not working like that. data has the following info:Resource {$promise: r, $resolved: true}$promise: r_bitField: 33554433_fulfillmentHandler0: (data)_promise0: undefined_receiver0: undefined_rejectionHandler0: Resource__proto__: r$resolved: true__proto__: Resource

Comment: maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071785/how-to-retreive-httpresponsemessage-filename-in-javascript

Comment: The `$resource` service uses `angular.copy` to populate the `$resource` object and `angular.copy` ignores primitives. Either have your server return an object, add a response intercepter to transform the response to an object, or use the `$http` service.

Comment: Yes , i changed my c# code to return a Json object and it worked. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535245/georgeawg comment Changed My c# code as follows to return a Json Object and everything worked well.

```
    [HttpPut]
            [Route("DeleteFile")]
            public JObject DeleteFile(int cabinetFileID)
            {
                var fileName = cabinetDataAccess.GetFilePath(cabinetFileID);                  
                    var returnVal = cabinetDataAccess.DeleteCabinetFile(cabinetFileID, UserEmail);
 var jsonString = Json(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { returnVal }));
                return JObject.Parse(jsonString.Content);      
            }
```

In my AngularJs controller i am able to check `if(data.returnVal === -1)`