# Not able to expose the custom headers from WebAPI to client

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have written a program to download the pdf, word or txt file returned by web api and it's working fine. On server side I have used WebApi and client side AngularJs. Now the problem is, I also need the file name from api as well and for that I need to read the headers returned by api. But `reponse.headers` doesn't contains all the headers info. Below is my code:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTranscript(string key, int format)
    {
        var badRequest = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Not a valid input."); //ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Not a valid input."));
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jiraTaskKey))
        {
            return badRequest;
        }

        string transcript = _mediaCaptionService.GetTranscript(UserId, key);

        string fileName = "transcript";
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        if (format == (int)TranscriptFormat.PDF)
        {
            byte[] byteInfo = GeneratePDFTranscript(transcript);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(byteInfo);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            fileName = fileName + ".pdf";
        }
        else if (format == (int)TranscriptFormat.TXT)
        {
            response.Content = new StringContent(transcript, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
            fileName = fileName + ".txt";
        }
        else if (format == (int)TranscriptFormat.WORD)
        {                
            string transcriptFontName = "Arial";
            byte[] byteInfo = GenerateWordTranscript(transcript, transcriptFontName);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(byteInfo);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            fileName = fileName + ".doc";
        }
        else
        {
            return badRequest;
        }
        response.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
            FileName = fileName
        };
        //response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
        return response; //ResponseMessage(response);
    }
```

and in client side

```
  function getTranscriptResult(method, apiUrl, data) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: method,
            url: apiUrl,
            data: data,
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'

        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            debugger;
            var results = [];
            results.data = data;
            results.headers = headers();
            results.status = status;
            results.config = config;                
            deferred.resolve(results);

        }).error(function (error, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(error);

        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

But when I put the break point in above code, I get this:

[image]

Can you please tell me where is the problem in my code that I am not able to get the file name? Also please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Just a note: This has nothing to do with Chrome. If you use the URI to the service directly in Chrome you will notice that it will download the file, with the proper file name. Think you should change your title from "Google Chrome..." to "Angular..."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After adding below lines has solved my problem.

```
// Add a custom header for filename and expose it to be consumed by JavaScript.
response.Content.Headers.Add("Filename", zipFileName);
response.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Filename");
```

So basically adding *Access-Control-Expose-Headers* helped me to expose the custom headers to client. For more information on this please follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)